# MySQL using Sum and Case

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, case

I'm trying to create a GridView with ASP.NET connecting to a MySQL database.  The data appears like below.

```
BusinessUnit    OrderDate      Canceled
UnitA           1/15/2013          N
UnitA           10/1/2013          N
UnitB           10/15/2013         N
UnitB           10/22/2013         N
UnitB           10/22/2013         N
```

Based on the records above, I'd like the result to appear like below

```
BusinessUnit  TodaysOrders   ThisMonthsOrders  ThisYearsOrders
UnitA              0                1                2
UnitB              2                3                3
```

My current code is below.  It's giving me error (something about DatabaseName.sum does not exist. Check the 
Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section... )

```
Select  
    SUM (CASE WHEN (OrderDate)=DATE(NOW()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TodaysOrders,
    SUM (CASE WHEN YEAR(OrderDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(OrderDate) = MONTH(CURDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ThisMonthsOrders,
    SUM (CASE WHEN YEAR(main_order_managers.creation_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ThisYearsOrders
```

code continues

```
FROM OrderTable WHERE OrderTable.Canceled. <> 'Y';
```

Is Sum Case the best use here?

Comment: Your context of sum(case) is fine as intended, but per Peterm's answer on spacing may be your issue... (however, remove the period after Canceled. before the <> 'Y'  )

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The error is caused by the space between function name and parenthesis

```
SUM (CASE WHEN ...
   ^^
```

Read more [Function Name Parsing and Resolution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/function-resolution.html)

Try

```
SELECT BusinessUnit,
       SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate = CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TodaysOrders,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(OrderDate, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ThisMonthsOrders,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(OrderDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ThisYearsOrders
  FROM OrderTable
 WHERE Canceled <> 'Y'
 GROUP BY BusinessUnit
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f196/1)** demo