# SQL Get two columns with Yes or No

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query where I am selecting all the sendIntakes and grouping them by the officiant id, and year.

The sendResponse column is if they have responded, 0 being No, 1 being Yes.

```
                     SELECT officiantId, COUNT(*) as ct, sendResponse,
                     Year(created_at) as yr
                     FROM sendIntakes
                     Where sendResponse is not null                   

                     GROUP BY officiantId, sendResponse, YEAR(created_at)
                     ORDER BY officiantId, yr
                     DESC;
```

I did my count although it makes a new row if the count is 0 / 1

```
officiant id - 404 | ct - 2 | sendResponse 1 | yr 2017
officiant id - 404 | ct - 1 | sendResponse 0 | yr 2017
officiant id - 547 | ct - 1 | sendResponse 1 | yr 2017
```

Is there a way to get rid of the sendResponse, and have it as

```
officiant id - 404 | ct - 2 | Yes - 1 | No - 1 | yr 2017
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You can count each occurrence of yes and no (1 or 0) by getting rid of sendResponse in your `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT officiantId, COUNT(*) as ct, 
SUM(CASE WHEN sendResponse = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yes,
SUM(CASE WHEN sendResponse = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as No,
Year(created_at) as yr
FROM sendIntakes
Where sendResponse is not null                   

GROUP BY officiantId, YEAR(created_at)
ORDER BY officiantId, yr
DESC;
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') As Yes,
SUM(CASE WHEN sendResponse = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE) As No,
Year' at line 1

Comment: @Victor seems like the error was in the `END CASE`. You can try to look there if there's still a problem : [MySQL using Sum and Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529864/mysql-using-sum-and-case)

Comment: Just change the last `CASE` to `END`.